# access an array defined by 'pointer'

Tags: php, arrays

So I have multiples empty arrays that I want to fill, let's say

```
$a_tab = [];
$b_tab = [];
$c_tab = [];
```

I have an array containing some data, let's say

```
$data = ['a' => 'foo', 'b' => 'bar', 'c' => 'foobar'];
```

I wanted to be able to do something like this :

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $tab_name = $key . '_tab'; // so we have a variable that have the same name as one of the array we declared before
    $$tab_name[$value] = $value; // this should add 'foo' into $a_tab, 'bar' in $b_tab and 'foobar' in $c_tab
}
```

But no value is ever added to any array...

Could someone explain me what did I do wrong ?

---

PS : if you don't want pseudo-code, here is the code that I had when I faced the issue :

```
// $tab is a parameter of the current function

$done_courses = []; // the array where we are going to put every courses that already have been added in one bifurcation tab

$regex_wz = '/\_werkzoekende/';
$regex_bd = '/\_bediende/';
$regex_op = '/\_outplacement/';

$bifurcation_keys = ['wz_tab' => $regex_wz, 'bd_tab' => $regex_bd, 'op_tab' => $regex_op];

// create the 3 arrays
$wz_tab = [];
$bd_tab = [];
$op_tab = [];

foreach($tab as $key => $value) {
    foreach($bifurcation_keys as $tab_name => $regex) {
        if(preg_match($regex, $key)) {
             $n_k = preg_replace($regex, '', $key);
             $$tab_name[$n_k] = $value;
             if(!isset($done_courses[$n_k])) {
                 $done_courses[$n_k] = $n_k;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try..

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    ${$key.'_tab'}[$value] = $value; 
}
```

Comment: yeah that's the way, I figured this out just now...
thanks for the answer :)

Do you know what's the name of the use of '$$' ?

Comment: i tink it's called `reference reference variable`

Comment: references are more like `&$variable`